# Taylor polynomial manipulation

Tags: calculus, summation, taylor-expansion

Find
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^k}{k}$

This is in a section in my book on Taylor polynomials/Taylor series so I assume we have to find some way to manipulate Taylor polynomials to get this. I think the best way to do that would be to find two Taylor polynomials that multiply to get that summation but I am unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote

$$\begin{align}f(x)&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^k}{k}\end{align}$$

Derive

$$\begin{align} f'(x)&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}x^{k-1}\\ &=\frac{1}{1+x} \end{align}$$

And $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$

Comment: I hadn't thought to take the derivative of the original summation, sneaky tactics Mr. Marwalix, sneaky tactics. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{x^k}{k}=\log(1+x)$$

One way to show this is to write

$$F(x,\lambda)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{\lambda^k x^k}{k}$$

Now, if $|\lambda x|<1$, we can differentiate under the integral and obtain

$$\frac{\partial F(x,\lambda)}{\partial x}= \lambda \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-\lambda x)^k $$

This series is a geometric series that can be evaluated in closed form.  The result is

$$\frac{\partial F(x,\lambda)}{\partial x}= \frac{ \lambda}{1+\lambda x}$$

Integrating with respect to $x$, using $F(0,\lambda)=0$, and letting $\lambda \to 1$ yields

$$F(x,\lambda=1)= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{x^k}{k}= \log(1+x)$$

as expected!!